# React Bootstrap ToggleButtonGroup and multiple selection

Tags: reactjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, react-bootstrap

I have the following `ToggleButtonGroup`:

```
<ToggleButtonGroup name="test">
    {categories.map(category => (
        <ToggleButton>{category.name}</ToggleButton>  
    ))}
</ToggleButtonGroup>
```

However it only allows selection of one item. If I toggle an item on then the previous one will be toggled off. Is there a way to allow multiple selection so more than one item can be toggled on?

Would love to hear some answers for this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[type="checkbox"](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/buttons/#controlled) Is the thing you need

```
//select initial buttons if the values 1 or 3
const [value, setValue] = useState([1, 3]);

<ToggleButtonGroup type="checkbox" onChange={handleChange} value={value}>....

const handleChange = (val) => {
    //val is an array of selected values of buttons
    setValue(val);
};
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-hm7ruw?file=src%2FApp.js)

Comment: This doesn't work. If I select one button suddenly they are all selected.

Comment: @Kex have you checked the demo, it's working fine right?

Comment: @Kex what i have provided is a demo you have to add a `value` prop to the `<ToggleButton>..`

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is how it's intended to be; toggling buttons to get only one value from them. However, you can use check-boxes instead and style them accordingly.